# Multiple rows in Glidejs slider

Tags: javascript, slider, glidejs

I use [glidejs](https://github.com/glidejs/glide) slider, And I have use case that require me to show two slider's rows, Is there a option to use multiple rows in this slider?

This is the ux/ui provided

[image]

I searched a lot, there is no option mentioned in the [official docs](https://glidejs.com/docs/options/). And there is still [open issue](https://github.com/glidejs/glide/issues/531) not resolved yet, not helpful feedbacks.

I these is any solution or trick?